# What kind of stucco is used in this style?

Tags: water, pool, interior, stucco

I am following a site on Instagram which centers around mediterranean styled homes. A common feature is the beige stucco, that is also being used for wet applications like pools and ponds. I have added example pictures below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

From experience I know that normal stucco is hard to waterproof, so I am interested if this is some special brand or mixture.

What kind of stucco-like material/finish is used in these Mediterranean style homes?

Comment: [Cynicism may follow…] In the Med, it's just cement render - smooth, "rustic" or "can't be bothered" finish, the difference would be the sand grain size, little else.. Almost all houses are cinder/cement block on concrete poured framing, occasionally hollow brick, render is the 'finish' to cover up the lack of care & attention to the actual build quality. The stuff in & around the pool may have an additional waterproof admix… but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 1):

No one will be able to give a definite answer, so I may as well provide a research direction that I happened to see on a This Old House segment.

There are a few special plaster mixtures and treatments used for water proof surfaces to have seamless-looking walls/floors with water fixtures like sinks, showers, etc. On of these is called [Tadelakt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadelakt), a type used in Moroccan architecture. The linkes article also references a few other types from elsewhere in the world.